# Android 6 BroadcastReceicer and call service

Tags: android, mobile, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I developed an app that needs to call the tomtom services at a specific time. For earlier version of the Android 6 I have instantiated an alert and performed the work when it enters BroadcastReceiver.
From version 6 onwards google rejects my app because I can not use the REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS and consequently my alarm does not work because it is closed by the system.

I read Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), but do not think in my case

there is a solution to my problem?

i want call an specific tom tom service at a specific time.

thanks

My code to setAlarm:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=22) {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmDate.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"SETTATO ALLARME PER API MAGGIORE DI 19 O MINORE UGUALE A 22");


            } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>22){
                alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmDate.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
            //  alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(alarmDate.getTimeInMillis(), sender), sender);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"SETTATO ALLARME PER API MAGGIORE O UGUALE A 23");
            }else { 
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"SETTATO ALLARME CON VERSIONE API INFERIORE A 19");
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmDate.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
            }
```

my code to call service:

```
String result=readUrl("https://api.tomtom.com/lbs/services/route/3/........."); 
private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                int read;
                char[] chars = new char[1024];
                while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                    buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

                return buffer.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                 Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERRORE:"+e.getMessage());
            }finally {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();

            }
            return buffer.toString();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have internet access, I don't see any reason why you can't use GCM to trigger your http request.